# How to test multiple return values with python?

Tags: python, return, python-unittest

So I have this function which returns sine and cosine and another basic unittest function which is supposed to test both return values with assertEqual, but I don't know how to test both of the return values. What's the best way to do that?

```
def calc_sin_cos(sindeg, cosdeg):
    sine = math.sin(math.radians(sindeg))
    cosine = math.cos(math.radians(cosdeg))

    return sine, cosine

def test_calc_sin_cos(self):
    sine = 2
    cosine = 2
    result = myscript.calc_sin_cos(sine, cosine)
    self.assertEqual(result, 0.03489949670250097, 0.9993908270190958)
```

Obviously the above assertEqual doesn't work properly as it is.

Comment: It is important to understand, you can ever only have a single return value. You are returning a tuple of length 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the method returns multiple values, it is a `tuple` in fact, the 2 following lines are identical:

```
return sine, cosine
return (sine, cosine)
```

For the calling method, these are same

```
result = myscript.calc_sin_cos(sine, cosine)
sin, cos = myscript.calc_sin_cos(sine, cosine)
```

---

To test them use `assertEqual`

- with both values so as a `tuple`

  ```
  result = myscript.calc_sin_cos(sine, cosine)
  self.assertEqual(result, (0.03489949670250097, 0.9993908270190958))
  ```
- or both values individually

  ```
  sin, cos = myscript.calc_sin_cos(sine, cosine)
  self.assertEqual(sin, 0.03489949670250097)
  self.assertEqual(cos, 0.9993908270190958)
  ```

---

For `float` values, it can use useful to use [`unittest.assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual)

```
  self.assertAlmostEqual(sin, 0.034, places=3)
  self.assertAlmostEqual(cos, 0.999, places=3)
```